# Preposition with "entwickelt"

Tags: grammar, preposition

> Ich will Deutsch lernen, weil ich glaube, Deutschland ist entwickelt in der Technologie und den Wissenschaften, und dafür interessiere ich mich sehr. Ich hoffe, dass ich eines Tages in Deutschland arbeiten kann.

What is the correct preposition to use with "entwickelt" here? Is it "in" or "mit" or some other preposition? Also, it would be great if you could comment on the whole sentences as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentences are almost correct, well done. Indeed the preposition used with *entwickelt* is *in*. There are few minor improvements for style only:

1. Reading may be easier if we do not omit the *dass* introducing the nested relative clause. We then can use a *zu* construction in the second sentence to avoid a double *dass*.
2. The word order in the relative clause should be: subject - object - verb.
3. In your context we would use *hoch entwickelt* rather than *entwickelt*.
4. Whenever you do not refer to a special technology or science it is better to leave out the article, use singular in both cases.
5. We have a common phrase *"Wissenschaft und Technik"* which may be used here. If you insist on *Technologie* (which is fine) you may want to change the word order to "Wissenschaft und Technologie".
6. Alternatively, you can use the adjectives *"wissenschaftlich"* and *"technologisch"*.

The resulting sentence would then read

> Ich will Deutsch lernen, weil ich glaube, dass Deutschland in Wissenschaft und Technik hoch entwickelt ist, und dafür interessiere ich mich sehr. Ich hoffe, eines Tages in Deutschland arbeiten zu können.

or

> Ich will Deutsch lernen, weil ich glaube, dass Deutschland wissenschaftlich und technologisch hoch entwickelt ist, und dafür interessiere ich mich sehr. Ich hoffe, eines Tages in Deutschland arbeiten zu können.

Comment: You can only leave out the article because you have two nouns `Wissenschaft` and `Technik`. If you used only one of them, you'd have to use the definite article.